# git mirror repo with pull and push

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

I need a solution to following problem. I have some workarounds, But I would like to know what's the proper way to do it.

Problem Statement:
I want to have source on my local machine (M).
However I can only build on remote machine (S).
Source is in git repo (G).
How can I develop on M. Build on S. Then push to G?

What I think is way to do:
Is there a way to say clone G on S, then clone S to M.
I make changes on M, push them to S. Do the build on S. If everything okay, push from S to M. I would like to know exact CLIs for this. Would there be any issues with push, pull, commit etc in this case?

Please suggest if you think there is altogether different way to do this.

Comment: Goodness, please don't use letters.  Call local `local`. Call the remote central repository where the final source is stored just "the remote" or `origin` (with is the generally used default in git itself), and how about calling the build machine `build`.  This is similar to how you should name variables in your code for it to be easily readable and understandable - this makes my head spin!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but why can't you just pull/push to origin on both the local and build machines.

Comment: This being said, is there a reason you don't want your work-in-progress on the central repo in a feature branch?